# Get total size of my hard drive in Linux, using the command line, without root permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, command-line

I'm trying to find out the total size of my hard drive using `df -h`, but it prints the size of each partition and requires `sudo`.

Is there any way to get total size of my hard drive using the command line, without requiring root permission?

Comment: Note: Using `df` is imprecise if the disk has unpartitioned space, not all partitions are mounted (e.g., some Windows partitions on the same drive) or some partitions are not mounted directly but indirectly through RAID, LVM or LUKS (encryption). It will also miss the swap partition(s). So I recommend *not* to use `df` for finding out the HDD size.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A hacky way is to bypass the need for `sudo` by reading out the system log with:

```
dmesg | grep blocks
```

Please note that this might not be ideal, so your mileage may vary...

Comment: This answer would be so much better if it explained what to expect or what is required for the command to print the desired information. In case "somebody's mileage varies" they may not recognize it. [This has happened at least once](https://superuser.com/q/1653378/432690).

Comment: what's expected is details of the drive as the question asked, but it's using log messages that may vary between systems so it's not possible to give guidance beyond suggesting to try it. On most systems it will give the information requested most of the time.

Comment: In my machine, it did not return the hard disk I have, but instead returns


[23629.376563] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 83886080 512-byte logical blocks: (42.9 GB/40.0 GiB)

Comment: Yeah definitely NOT ideal, pretty useless if you have multiple drives mounted.

Comment: How to convert this to MiB or GiB?

Answer (score 21):

If you want the size in bytes and only the value e.g. for scripting:

```
lsblk -b --output SIZE -n -d /dev/sdX
12220202
```

*-b*: Output in bytes.
*-n*: No headings. We only want the pure number value.
*--output SIZE*:  Only print the size-column.
*-d /dev/sdXn*: The device which size we want to know. X is e.g.  d, n is e.g, 1  for first partition of disk d.

Advantages:

- root privileges are not needed

  grep is not needed

  lsblk is available on most linux systems

Comment: Why use that over something like `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdx`?

Comment: @AlienDrew maybe because this answer works and the one you've provided doesn't?

Comment: @lacostenycoder ... You realize this comment was like over a year ago right?

Comment: @AlienDrew I do see that. In the case where your comment no longer applies, you can simply delete it. I'll delete mine, everything stays cleaner.

Comment: To get human-readable size, just pipe the output to `numfmt --to=si`

Answer (score 6):

```
cat /sys/block/sda/size
```

But the size is in block-based unit
I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960421/how-can-i-determine-the-space-size-of-my-drive-programatically-both-in-linux-an).
Other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027037/determine-the-size-of-a-block-device).

Or you can try **udisks**

```
udisks --show-info /dev/sda | egrep "^[[:space:]]*size" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use that information in a script for example, using

```
sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/sda
```

might be easier than fdisk or hdparm as it only gives you the relevant information (just multiply by 512). However, it will also require sudo.

You could of course change the configuration of sudo such that it allows to execute this specific command without asking for the password (I guess `blockdev --getsz` is pretty safe even when executed by a normal non-privileged user).

This would be done by adding the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
ALL ALL= NOPASSWD:/sbin/blockdev --getsz /dev/*
```

When you edit this file, be sure to use the command `sudo visudo` and not your usual editor. Otherwise it is very easy to make a syntax error, which would result in not being able to use sudo anymore (you would have to reboot into rescue mode to fix this).

Comment: From the man page: `--getsize64 Print device size in bytes.`. Also [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52223/18887).

Comment: OP asked for "without root/sudo privlages"

Answer (score 3):

I'm not at my Linux box right now, but you could try:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

or

```
fdisk -l
```

which will also probably require a sudo.

I haven't seen anywhere that df requires root.  That's odd.

Comment: Maybe "df" is not in PATH. HVNSweeting, try "sudo which df" and then try that as user.

Comment: hi, this is what i get:
hvnsweeting@hvnbox:~$ blockdev --getsz /dev/sda
/dev/sda: Permission denied
hvnsweeting@hvnbox:~$ hdparm -I /dev/sda
/dev/sda: Permission denied
hvnsweeting@hvnbox:~$ fdisk -l
hvnsweeting@hvnbox:~$

Comment: Everything which accesses the devices directly (i.e., /dev/sda) will need sudo.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` best answer for fast look at all partitions but does require `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

You either have a bad install or an absurdly paranoid sysadmin. I've *never* heard of `df` requiring root privileges before.  And I've worked with quite a few different flavors of unix/unix-like operating systems.

Anyhow, this will give you the total size of all disk partitions (first `df` column is `/dev/hd...` or `/dev/sd...`) in blocks (kB):

```
df | grep '^/dev/[hs]d' | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}'
```

or in GB:

```
df | grep '^/dev/[hs]d' | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s/1048576}'
```

Comment: Beautiful... `df | grep '^/dev/' | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s/1048576}'` we are now using it in SlickStack. Any derivative to find remaining (free) space?

Answer (score 1):

Checking Disk Space From Gnome and Kubuntu

Disk Usage Analyzer is a graphical menu driven application that reports disk usage in Gnome and Kubuntu environments. DUA (Disk Usage Analyzer) can scan the entire file system tree or individual directories, either local or remote. DUA is also dynamic, in that it will report in real time any devices that are mounted and unmounted.

To access Disk Usage Analyzer in Gnome, click on: Applications \ Accessories \ Disk Usage Analyzer
its that simple.