# “dmesg | grep blocks” - Does this command really show the total disk space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dmesg

I want to know the total disk space of my Ubuntu server. I found this question: [*Get total size of my hard drive in Linux, using the command line, without root permissions*](https://superuser.com/q/351251). The [accepted and most upvoted answer](https://superuser.com/a/351514) advises the following command:

> ```
> dmesg | grep blocks
> ```

I run it and this is what I got:

```
EXT4-fs (xvda1): resizing filesystem from 2096891 to 39321339 blocks
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to understand what the above line means. I doubt I can easily tell the total size of my hard drive from these numbers. The message is cryptic to me. So why is the linked answer upvoted? What else should I know to "decode" the message?

Or is my case somewhat special? Do others get less cryptic result from `dmesg | grep blocks`? I have a feeling there is something non-standard going on. My additional concern is, is it resizing disk space in the server or something? Should I be worried?

Please help me understand what `dmesg | grep blocks` is supposed to do in the context of the linked answer. Is the line I got an expected result? How can I get the total size of my disk from it?

I roughly know what `dmesg` and `grep` do on their own.

Comment: I think you need to do some research on your own... There are even Wikipedia articles about both dmesg _and_ grep.

Comment: This command definitely does not check the total disk space.

Comment: `xvd` (`xvda1`) is [apparently specific to Xen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166083/what-is-the-dev-xvda1-device) Virtual Disk devices. This is almost certainly only going to work out the disk size of a server that has spun up with an initial "image" applied to the start of a virtual disk and then resized to fill the disk.

Comment: @gronostaj, I have found the code from one of the superuser posts.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Hi, if I have posted it in an improper way, then sorry for that. But as you said that those two are distinct questions, I do not agree with that. Becasue when I use the "$ dmesg | grep blocks" command, it gave me the response. So how those two are different?

Comment: If you used `grep be` on the plain text of Hamlet, one of the lines in the output would contain `To be, or not to be`. The meaning of the phrase has nothing to do with what `grep` does.

Comment: @user1686 Yes, you are right, actually I had some urgency to know what the response indicates, that is why I have posted it here.

Comment: You really shouldn't be running random commands from strangers on the Internet without understanding what they do. It's a sure way to wreck your system.

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, you are right but if you find that the answer is accepted as the best answer by the owner then probably you will think that this is the solution to your problem, is not it?

Comment: By the way, thanks all for commenting on this post. If you think it's a silly question, then leave it but do not post such things which are not solving my problem.

Comment: It was the solution to original asker's problem, not yours. Checking total disk space in Linux isn't done like this, unless you have some very specific requirements for some reason - and even then you'd need additional information to make sense of that number.

Comment: Done. I also upvoted the question now. Make sure you roughly know what `dmesg` and `grep` do. Good luck.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked answer calls the command "a hacky way" and says "this might not be ideal". There are reasons for this. Unfortunately the answer does not say what to expect nor what is required for the command to work. No wonder you got confused.

The command did not show you what the author of the linked answer thought of. The line you saw has nothing to do with what the author had in mind.

You wrote you roughly know what `dmesg` and `grep` do. For the general audience let's make it clear:

- `dmesg` prints the kernel ring buffer; think of the buffer as of a log that tells you what happened in the guts of your Linux OS.
- `grep` filters its input and prints lines matching a pattern; in case of `grep blocks` the pattern is `blocks`.
- `dmesg | grep blocks` gets the kernel ring buffer and filters it, so only lines containing the string `blocks` pass through; indeed the line you got contains the string.

When I run `dmesg | grep blocks` in my Kubuntu 18.04.5 LST, the output is like:

```
[    6.028374] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/112 GiB)
[    6.635725] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/699 GiB)
```

It's not the entire output, I omitted few irrelevant lines. What I did not omit is the part I think the author of the linked answer had in mind. From these lines one can easily tell the sizes of my disks.

`dmesg | grep blocks` may print nothing like these and the reason(s) may be:

- One may need `sudo` to run `dmesg`. This is how it works in my Debian 10. In your case this reason apparently does not apply: if you needed `sudo`, you would get a clear error (`operation not permitted` or so), not the line you got.
- What `dmesg` prints is a buffer and its size is limited. If the buffer is full then new entries will make the buffer drop old entries. In a long-running OS the entries relevant in the context of the linked answer may have already been dropped (they may still be in `/var/log/kern.log` or similar log). While this may have happened in your case, I doubt it did actually happen. Usually you can tell if dropping began by analyzing `dmesg | head`. If the [timestamps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382922/108618) are `0.000000` then you know the buffer still stores events from when the kernel booted, so later entries should also still be there.
- The buffer does not and did not contain entries the author of the linked answer had in mind. This is what probably happened in your case.

The example entries I've shown come from the sd driver responsible for managing devices like `sda` or `sdb`. Originally these names meant SCSI disks. Nowadays it's not limited to SCSI. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144565/108618), especially from where it says:

> Today, Linux calls most rewritable mass-storage devices `/dev/sd?`.

You most likely don't have any `sd?` device in the OS in question, that's why you observed no lines from the sd driver. The line you observed mentions `xvda1`, this and similarly named devices are [specific to Xen](https://askubuntu.com/a/166087/693277).

Note the fact the sd driver generates a message like

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/112 GiB)
```

is only because someone at some point though it was useful. In general block device drivers are not required to report the size of each device this way. Whatever handles your `xvda1` does not generate such message.

Now it should be clear the linked answer kinda abuses `dmesg`. The answer is upvoted because the vast majority of non-virtual Linux OSs actually uses disks handled by the sd driver. The answer is accepted only because the author of the question there liked it the most. In its current state the answer gives a potentially useful solution without any insight; IMO it's not a high quality answer.

Now the line you got:

> ```
> EXT4-fs (xvda1): resizing filesystem from 2096891 to 39321339 blocks
> ```

appeared because it was in the buffer at the time and it contains `blocks` (the pattern `grep blocks` searches for); but it has nothing to do with what the author of the linked answer had in mind. In some sense `dmesg | grep blocks` printed it by chance.

The line is probably from `resize2fs`, a tool designed to resize filesystems from the ext family. This is what you should know:

- The line indicates the filesystem on `xvda1` has been resized. Keep in mind everything `dmesg` prints is a log, everything in the log has already happened. The resizing happened after the OS last started (i.e. not before the last reboot) but certainly not because you invoked `dmesg`.
- I cannot tell you why the resizing happened. Even if it happened because of some automation (and I don't claim it did), I certainly don't expect it to happen every time you reboot.
- `resize2fs` can enlarge a filesystem online (i.e. when it's mounted). If everything works then there's nothing to be worried about. Remember the resizing has already happened.
- The line cannot really tell you the total disk space because:

  - it tells you the filesystem now takes 39321339 blocks but it doesn't tell you how big one block is;
  - but even if you knew how big one block is, 39321339 blocks is the new size of the filesystem, the device itself may be larger;
  - and the device is `xvda1`, so probably it's a partition of some `xvda` which is even larger, maybe substantially larger;
  - and there may be other block devices.

Using `dmesg | grep blocks` to find out the sizes of block devices is like searching for the word "weight" in a farmer's diary to learn the weight of each of his pigs. Maybe the diary mentions the weights, maybe not; maybe it mentions the farmer's weight (or his wife's). A proper method is to put each pig on a scale. In your case the command tells nothing useful. Find another command, something actually designed for the job, like the scale is designed to measure weight. My first choice would be `lsblk` or `lsblk -b`. Note `lsblk` prints sizes of block devices (similarly to what the command in question would print in the right circumstances), not sizes of filesystems nor free space in filesystems.